# How to sum an attribute's object from a stack of objects?

Tags: java, object, stack

I have a class car with constructor as

```
public car (String name, int numberOfCars, int price) {}
```

Then, in my main, I created stack as:

```
Stack<car>carStack = new Stack<car>();
carStack.push("Honda", 200, 19000));
carStack.push("Toyota", 300, 18000));
carStack.push("BMW", 150, 40000));
```

How can I get the price of 500 cars (150 BMW + 300 Toyota + 50 Honda) from this stack?

Comment: Iterate your stack in a foor-loop and sum!

Comment: By convention class name should be capitalized: `Car` instead of `car`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

- Iterate through the Stack with a for loop. Stack implements the Iterable interface, and so a for-each loop is probably the easiest to use: `for (Car myCar: carStack) {...}`
- call getPrice() on the items in the loop
- add this to a sum variable that has been declared *before* the loop
- Q.E.D.

As an aside, to have your code comply with Java naming standards, your car class should be renamed **C**ar. Class and interface names should begin with an upper case letter.

Since someone else is showing off code, here's my big whoop code snippet:

```
double price = 0.0;
for (Car myCar: carStack) {
  price += myCar.getPrice();
}
```

Comment: When I did that I got the price of (150 BMW + 300 Toyota + 200 Honda). Is it possible to get the price of (150 BMW + 300 Toyota + 50 Honda)?

Comment: @Gantavya: ???? you'll get the price of whatever has been added to the stack, no more, and no less. Period.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate your stack within a **foreach-loop**:

```
double price = 0.0;

for(Car c : stack)
{
    price += c.getPrice();
}
```

Or you can iterate your stack within a **while-loop**:

```java
Iterator<Car> iter = carStack.iterator();
double price = 0.0;

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    price += iter.next().getPrice();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can use a [MutableStack](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/stack/MutableStack.html) which has the method `sumOfInt()`.

```
Car honda = new Car("Honda", 19000);
Car toyota = new Car("Toyota", 18000);
Car bmw = new Car("BMW", 40000);

MutableStack<Car> carStack =
        ArrayStack.newStackFromTopToBottom(honda, toyota, bmw);

long price = carStack.sumOfInt(new IntFunction<Car>()
{
    @Override
    public int intValueOf(Car eachCar)
    {
        return eachCar.getPrice();
    }
});
Assert.assertEquals(77000, price);
```

The question mentions that each car has a number of occurrences. Perhaps a [Bag](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/8.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/Bag.html) would be a more appropriate data structure than a `StackIterable`. A `Bag` keeps track of items and how many times the item occurs in the `Bag`. It would mean deleting the `numberOfCars` field from `Car`.

```
MutableBag<Car> carBag = HashBag.newBag();
carBag.addOccurrences(honda, 200);
carBag.addOccurrences(toyota, 300);
carBag.addOccurrences(bmw, 150);

long price = carBag.sumOfInt(new IntFunction<Car>()
{
    @Override
    public int intValueOf(Car eachCar)
    {
        return eachCar.getPrice();
    }
});
Assert.assertEquals(15200000, price);
```

When Java 8 is released, we can replace the anonymous inner class with a lambda or method reference. Here's what the code will look like with a method reference.

```
long price = carBag.sumOfInt(Car::getPrice);
```

If price were a double instead of an int, we'd just need to replace `sumOfInt()` with `sumOfDouble()`.

```
long price = carBag.sumOfDouble(Car::getPrice);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
int total = 0;
while(!cars.isEmpty()) {
    total += cars.pop().getTotal();
}
```

Then Car's getTotal:

```
public double getTotal() {
    return price * quantity;
}
```

Or if you want to preserve stack, do the foreach that others have mentioned.